# Foreign key constraint in REST API

Tags: rest

I'm designing RESTful API for trip planner application and don't know how to enforce foreign key constraint on resource creation. I have two resources: `Trip` and `User`. `Trip` resource looks like this:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  //some other attributes
  "tripParticipants":[ 
    {
      "id": 1
    }
   ]
}
```

where `tripParticipants` is collection of `User` ids. `TripParticipants` should only contain created `Users` (by created I mean stored in database).

I have trouble with endpoint `POST /trips/{id}/tripParticipants` to add elements to the collection. 
What should I return when `User` with given id doesn't exist in my database? Returning `HTTP 404` status code for `POST` operation looks weird. Does REST standard defines some solutions to this use case?

Comment: I would do 404 only if the trip id was wrong (that is not weird), and 400 Bad Request if something else in the request body is invalid (such as a missing user id).

Comment: @Thilo, 400 should be used for requests invalid in terms of syntax - which rarely happens, nowadays.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two HTTP status codes that can be used in this situation:

- [`422 Unprocessable entity`](https://httpstatuses.com/422)
- [`409 Conflict`](https://httpstatuses.com/409)

Both are correct for your scenario. Personally I'd go with `422`.

Answer (score -1):

For Rest you follow the Http standard status codes, so 404 is the appropriate code for Rest.

These are the status codes you could be using https://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html